# g++ warning: ISO C++ forbids converting a string constant to 'char*' при запуске sqlite

Tags: c++, c, sqlite, gcc, g++

Запускаю простейший пример, c habr, иллюстрирующий работу с базой данных sqlite.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>
#include "sqlite3.h"
using namespace std;

const char* SQL = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS foo(a,b,c); INSERT INTO FOO VALUES(1,2,3); INSERT INTO FOO SELECT * FROM FOO;";

int main(int argc, char **argv){
cout << "begining" << endl;
sqlite3 *db = 0; // хэндл объекта соединение к БД
char *err = 0;

// открываем соединение
if( sqlite3_open("my_db.db", &db) )
fprintf(stderr, "Ошибка открытия/создания БД: %s\n", sqlite3_errmsg(db));
// выполняем SQL
else if (sqlite3_exec(db, SQL, 0, 0, &err))
{
fprintf(stderr, "Ошибка SQL: %sn", err);
sqlite3_free(err);
}
// закрываем соединение
sqlite3_close(db);
cout << "end" << endl;
return 0;
}
```

Компилирую с помощью g++:

```
 g++ -o start_cpp start_cpp.cpp sqlite3.c
```

Получаю целую кучу ошибок, связанных с конвертацией типов в sqlite3.c. Например:

```
sqlite3.c:21495:1: warning: ISO C++ forbids converting a string constant to 'char*' [-Wwrite-strings]
sqlite3.c: In function 'void strftimeFunc(sqlite3_context*, int, sqlite3_value**)':
sqlite3.c:21929:29: error: invalid conversion from 'void*' to 'char*' [-fpermissive]
     z = sqlite3DbMallocRawNN(db, (int)n);
```

Как же правильно скомпилировать, чтобы не возникало такой проблемы?

Если убрать хэдер iostream и функции вывода cout, переименовать start_cpp.cpp в start.c и скомпилировать через gcc:

```
 gcc -o start start.c sqlite3.c
```

то всё работает!! НО! Для дальнейшей работы интересует именно .cpp файл, а не .c

Как правильно использовать sqlite3.h и sqlite3.c???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вы собираете С файл компилятором С++. Для правильного использования `sqlite3.c` следует собрать отдельно компилятором C. Затем прилинковать в свой проект.

Comment: Следующие строки компиляции привели к успеху:
g++ -c start_cpp.cpp
gcc -c  sqlite3.c
g++ -o start_cpp start_cpp.o sqlite3.o
Спасибо VTT за наводку